# How to specify Google Cloud Run metadata in Github Actions?

Tags: docker, yaml, github-actions, google-cloud-run

I have a Github Action which builds a docker image then uploads it to the Container Registry.
Next I want to deploy this container to a Cloud Run service with some specific settings for the min and max instances, ensure CPU is always on, internal ingress only, etc. The documentation says [these settings are set using metadata](https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun#metadata-customizations), but no example is shown. What format should this metadata take?

```yaml
name: Push code to GCP
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
jobs:
  container-build-push-deploy:
    name: Build Container Push to Registry Deploy to Cloud Run
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      IMAGE_NAME: my-image
      PROJECT_ID: my-project-123456
      REGION: us-central1
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Authenticate With GCP
      id: auth
      uses: google-github-actions/auth@v0
      with:
        credentials_json: ${{ secrets.GCP_CREDENTIALS }}

    - name: Setup Cloud SDK
      uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v0
      with:
        project_id: ${{ env.PROJECT_ID }}
    
    - name: Tag Release
      id: increment-git-tag
      run: |
        bash ./scripts/git_update.sh -v patch

    - name: Build Docker Image
      run: docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME:latest .
    
    - name: Configure Docker Client
      run: |-
        gcloud auth configure-docker --quiet

    - name: Push Docker Image to Container Registry
      env:
        GIT_TAG: ${{ steps.increment-git-tag.outputs.git-tag }}
      run: |-
        docker tag $IMAGE_NAME:latest gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$IMAGE_NAME:latest
        docker tag $IMAGE_NAME:latest gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$IMAGE_NAME:$GIT_TAG
        docker push gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$IMAGE_NAME:latest
        docker push gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$IMAGE_NAME:$GIT_TAG
    
    - name: Deploy to Cloud Run
      env:
        GIT_TAG: ${{ steps.increment-git-tag.outputs.git-tag }}
      uses: google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun@v0
      with:
        service: my-service
        image: 'gcr.io/${{ env.PROJECT_ID }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}:${{ env.GIT_TAG }}'
        region: ${{ env.REGION }}
        secrets: |
          /app/path/to/my-secret=my-secret:latest
        metadata:
          min-instances: 1
          max-instances: 1
          ingress: internal
          tag: ${{ env.GIT_TAG }}
          no-cpu-throttling: true
          command: node
          args: |
            /app/path/to/main.js
            arg-1
```

Obviously this last `metadata` piece is wrong since `with` is supposed to be key-value pairs of string. What is the correct format here?

Comment: The [repo](https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun) has an issue that may help: [How do you provide the filepath to the `metadata`](https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun/issues/247)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [link that you share](https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun#metadata-customizations), the specs of your Cloud Run Service can be stored in a yaml file.

> You can store your service specification in a YAML file

So I created a yaml (ex: service.yaml) file and pushed it to the `github repository`.

Sample **service.yaml** file code with **min and max instances, number of cpu and internal ingress**

```yaml
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
      name: my-service
      annotations:
        run.googleapis.com/ingress: internal
        run.googleapis.com/cpu-throttling: 'False'
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        autoscaling.knative.dev/minScale: '2'
        autoscaling.knative.dev/maxScale: '50'
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: <IMAGE_URL>
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: '2'
```

And here is the `Deploy to Cloud Run` steps **yaml file**

```yaml
- name: Deploy to Cloud Run
  uses: google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun@v0
  with:
    region: ${{ env.REGION }}
    metadata: service.yaml
```

Additional Info: You can use the [sed command](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sed-command-in-linux-unix-with-examples/) in linux to edit or replace string of a files even without opening them

```yaml
- name: Set Image Name
  run: your_sed_command
```

Comment: Nice! Ironically this seems more verbose than the cli method.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going the pure CLI route in the interest of saving time

```yaml
    - name: Deploy to Cloud Run
      env:
        GIT_TAG: ${{ steps.increment-git-tag.outputs.git-tag }}
        SERVICE: my-service
        MY_ARG: arg-1
      run: |
        gcloud run deploy $SERVICE --image=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$IMAGE_NAME:$GIT_TAG \
          --platform=managed --region=$REGION --min-instances=1 --max-instances=1 \
          --ingress=internal --tag=latest --no-cpu-throttling --no-allow-unauthenticated \
          --command=node --args=/app/path/to/main.js,$MY_ARG \
          --set-secrets=/app/path/to/my-secret=my-secret:latest
```

It would be nice to get another answer on how to use the pre-built setup-gcloud Github Action though from someone who knows.